# Execute code on Back Button Click (REACTJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below code is execute when I browse one page to another page for example. when I click on a product from the category page listing, the below code sets a session storage key that will have a position of the category page (how much page has been scrolled).

So when the product page will open it saves its key in session & if again it visited the same category page it restore the page position.

I am trying to make this code save only one session key & remove the previously saved session key regardless of which page the user clicks on the website (i.e category page, product page).

`CategoryPage.js`

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = React.useState('');

 React.useEffect(() => {
   var pathName = document.location.pathname.substr(1);
   if (window) {
     window.onscroll = function (e) {
       setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
       if(scrollPosition != 0){
         sessionStorage.setItem("scrollPosition_"+pathName, scrollPosition);
       }
     };
   }
 }, [scrollPosition]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
   var pathName = document.location.pathname.substr(1);
   if (window && sessionStorage.getItem("scrollPosition_"+pathName)) {
     $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition_'+ pathName));
     console.log('position_set to = ' + sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition_'+ pathName));
   }
 }, []);
```

any thoughts on this to remove the previous session key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand is upon loading a page, you want to:

1. If this page was the last visited page: load its saved location.
2. Else: remove the last saved location and save it upon scrolling.

Then it looks like you need to save some sort of page ID with the location you're saving/loading. This unique identifier can clearly be the URL.

Then, you can use a similar version of your code:

```
 const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = React.useState('');
 const getPathname = () => document.location.pathname.substr(1);

 React.useEffect(() => {
   if (window) {
     window.onscroll = function (e) {
       setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
       if (scrollPosition != 0) {
         const savedPosition = { position: scrollPosition, pathName: getPathname() };
         sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', JSON.stringify(savedPosition));
       }
     };
   }
 }, [scrollPosition]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
   const lastSavedPosition = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'));
   if (window && lastSavedPosition && getPathname() === lastSavedPosition.pathName) {
      $(window).scrollTop(lastSavedPosition.position);
      console.log(`position_set to = ${lastSavedPosition.position}`);
   }
 }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i am trying to remove the previous session key and add the new key.

Comment: ReferenceError: position is not defined

console.log(`position_set to = ${position}`);

Comment: Yeah my bad, it should be `lastSavedPosition.position`. Updated my answer

Comment: can we use
setTimeout(()=>window.scrollTo(0, lastSavedPosition.position),10);
instead of

$(window).scrollTop(lastSavedPosition.position); ?

Comment: Sure, the logic I suggested was supposed to handle the saving and loading of the location, relatively to the URL. You can apply whatever logic you want around it :)

Comment: can you please take a look at this ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using redux with react you can actually make a reducer that tracks location by sending actions that contain the information if the user was on the product page.

Something like this:

So if you have few routes like:

```
/category/house/3213124(product_id)
/category/garden/dsfsdfs(product_id)
```

In your router you can adress them like this:

```
/category/house/{id}
/category/garden/{id}
```

Then you can use :

```
let { id } = useParams();

if(id !== undefined || ""){
     dispatch(userIsOnProductPageAction(true))
}
```

When users **click the back button** by ***using a selector*** for reducer you have information that was a user on the product page... **if *true* execute code, if *false* do nothing**.

Also after executing code you dispatch `userIsOnProductPageAction(false)`.

If you are not using redux, you can apply the same logic but problem is that you have to hold the state `wasUserOnPage` and somehow access it when on the category page.

Since I don't know how your React application looks I can't tell you how to achieve that. **If the product is a child element and the category is a parent element by clicking the back button you could probably send that information through props.**

EDIT: it should look something like this

```
    class main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
  }

  handler() {
    this.setState({
      wasOnProductPage:false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <Category handler = {this.handler} props={this.props.wasOnProductPage} />
            <Product handler = {this.handler} />
  }
}

class Category extends React.Component {
  render() {

    if(props){
        do code for viewport
        then acitave this.props.handler and set it to false
    }
  }
}

class Product extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <BackButton onClick = {this.props.handler(true)}/ >
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer,
React application is not using redux also product is not child element and the category is not a parent element.

May be we can observe back button click with router.beforePopState, But i am new to react so not much aware how to use it and set information on product page & if back button is clicked check if category page is rendered/came from product page.

Comment: If App component(main component) is holding state and product component is child element of the App component(it should be ) please read this: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-pass-props-object-from-child-component-to-parent-component  - Passing Props from Child to Parent. What you need to do is when back button is clicked you are sending props to App component and there you hold the state wasUserOnProduct page and change it from false to true. Then you have that information when you are on category component

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, i will take a look at it if its possible to pass data from product page to category page.

Comment: Just to be clear. You are holding state in main component. You change state from Product Component in main component. You send state from main component to Category component, after you read it in category component and execute code you are changing state again in main component from category component

Comment: <>You change state from Product Component in main component.<>
when this be done ? when back button is clicked from product page ?

Comment: Thankyou very much for the efforts you put in to answer the question.